# Reorder columns in a specific order

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

I have a 2D array, defined as:

```
using value_type = std::array<std::pair<int, QChar>, 4>;
std::vector<value_type> arr;
```

where `first` is the book-kept column number (read as `arr[col][j]`). The column numbers, when the array is being formed, are assigned in a sorted order (`0, 1, 2, 3`).

The user, at run time, can enter a "rule" in which the array will have to be reordered. For eg: `2, 0, 3, 1`

At the moment I have hard-coded this (=the above reordering rule) to:

```
for (auto& it : arr)
{
    std::swap(it[0], it[1]);
    std::swap(it[0], it[2]);
    std::swap(it[2], it[3]);
}
```

I want to give the user the ability to reorder things in various way; `[3, 1, 0, 2], [0, 3, 2, 1]`, and so on. How can I do this? :|

Comment: Add another layer of indirection - create a vector that maps the position in the user's order to original column, just like you used in your explanation. No data actually needs to move.

Comment: @AlanStokes, nice idea! Thanks. I'll try to implement it this way.